# UFT is very slow in identifying objects

Tags: object, qtp, identification

UFT is very slow in identifying objects, For example,

```
Browser("").Page("").Frame("").Image("").click
```

The above line takes 4-5 minutes to get clicked. If we manually pause the UFT, it is suddenly clicked and get paused. I have checked with all possible properties to identify that object. Object is a calender image

Comment: The line which you have mentioned doesnt have properties for any objects

Taking long time and doing just last step on pausing or stopping is a sign that QTP is not able to find the object and it goes into smart identification. Things to try:

1. Run by turning off smart idenfiticaion
2. Run by using Descriptive Programming.
3. Run only with Web Add-In
4. Just try running one single line to check whether the issue is with tool or your code.

Also check your setting for **Delay each step execution**  and **object synchronization timeout**

Comment: Before answering, I'd like to see the run result log of such a 4-5 minutes run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what solved my problem was to disable the Internet Explorer Add-on: HP Functional Testing Agent.

It's now working fast and perfect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep smart identification as False in Object repository.
2. For browser if index property is used make it None and try to identify the   object
3. If there are any variable in the object repository for example in the URL some numbers might change so use ".*"

Making all these changes try to highlight the object if it is highlighting then try running the script. All the best

Comment: if WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfObject("Order updated").Exist  returns False, but this steps takes 5-8 seconds to go ahead. Why is it so ? Can u pls help, the above steps works but takes time. There is no such runtime Object but it takes time to decide n go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with UFT 12.02, when i try to click 'sign in' link with the below code, UFT takes minimum 2mins to click it, sometimes script keeps on running without performing anything, I need to manually pause or stop execution. When i click pause or stop the below script will get executed.

**Browser("brw_HomePage").Page("pge_HomePage").Link("wlnk_SignIn").Click**

**OR details:**
innertext  - sign in
html tag - A
Ordinal identifier - none
Smart identification - False

While running

1. Disabled smart identification,
2. object synchronisation timeout as 20s. (also tried with 10s and 5s)
3. Tried with Normal and fast run mode.

Comment: if WpfWindow("HPE MyFlight Sample Application").WpfObject("Order updated").Exist  returns False, but this steps takes 5-8 seconds to go ahead. Why is it so ? Can u pls help, the above steps works but takes time. There is no such runtime Object but it takes time to decide n go ahead.